# Modern UI - Modern Menu won´t show link content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I´m writing a WPF application based on FirtsFloorSoftware Modern UI. I´m facing problems when I´m trying to show the content (UserControl) set with 'Source =' in a Link. To display the problem I have made a small separet app.

The problem is that the content of Link 2 (SecondPage.xaml) never shows. I have searched the internet for clues on how to resolve this but to no luck.

Please help me.

UPDATE - Added MainWindow.xaml

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="TestAvModernMenu.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                  Title="mui" 
                  LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z"
                  ContentSource="FirstPage.xaml"
                  >
    <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Group 1" >
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Link 1" Source="FirstPage.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestAvModernMenu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : ModernWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="TestAvModernMenu.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**FirstPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestAvModernMenu.FirstPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAvModernMenu"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <TextBlock Text="First page" />
        <mui:ModernMenu x:Name="mmPatientMenu" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <mui:ModernMenu.LinkGroups>
                <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Group 2">
                    <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                        <mui:Link DisplayName="Link 2" Source="SecondPage.xaml"></mui:Link>
                    </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                </mui:LinkGroup>
            </mui:ModernMenu.LinkGroups>
        </mui:ModernMenu>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**SecondPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestAvModernMenu.SecondPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAvModernMenu"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <TextBlock Text="Second page" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Best regards,
Fredrik

Comment: Can you add `MainWindow.xaml` please?

Comment: MainWindow.xaml added, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

On your `FirstPage.xaml` you could use a `ModernTab` eg

```
 <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <TextBlock Text="First page" />
    <mui:ModernTab Layout="List">
        <mui:ModernTab.Links>
            <mui:Link Source="/SecondPage.xaml" DisplayName="Second Page"></mui:Link>
        </mui:ModernTab.Links>
    </mui:ModernTab>
</StackPanel>
```

Alternatively you could navigate from FirstPage to SecondPage using code behind and grabbing the `Frame` object. See below

FirstPage.xaml

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <TextBlock Text="First page" />
    <Button x:Name="SecondPageButton" Content="Goto Second Page" Click="SecondPageButton_Click"></Button>
</Grid?
```

Navigate on Button Click event
FirstPage.xaml.cs

```
private void SecondPageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation.NavigationHelper.FindFrame(null, this);

    if (frame != null)
       frame.Source = new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will try that first thing on Monday. I´m still curious why the ModernMenu in FirstPage.xaml doesn´t show the content of it´s link (SecondPage.xaml). FirstFloorSoftware have a demo application (with source code) and in that application they are able to what I´m trying to accomplish. What am I doing wrong? Link to zip containing Demo app: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/releases/download/1.0.8/ModernUI.1.0.8.zip

Comment: Link to zip containing latest release: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/archive/1.0.9.zip

Comment: Hi. Go to Controls - Modern Controls - Modern Menu. Where the "Modern Menu"-page is my SecondPage.xaml.

Comment: Hi thanks for link. ModernMenu doesn't navigate to a new page but simply uses `SelectedLink` property (and `SelectedLinkGroup`) from the `mui.ModernMenu`. look [here](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Shared/Windows/Controls/ModernMenu.cs) to see the properties that page uses

Comment: Ok. I have double checked the FirstFloor code and they use a ModernTab in ControlsModern.xaml that would be "in between" my FirstPage and SecondPage, as you suggested in your answer. However, I still don´t understand why a ModernMenu, on a page linked to from a ModernWindow isn´t able to show it´s links content (As in my case).

Comment: Ok. I have completely over looked that piece of code :). I will crawl back in under what ever stone I came from. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no worries. ModernUI is cool but has its own way of doing things. good luck with your app